# arm-none-eabi build kernel7.img

Tags: assembly, operating-system, raspberry-pi

I have bought a Raspberry Pi 3 from vilros. After following this tutorial: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/downloads.html, I found that none of the lessons, even downloaded form the downloads page, do not work. After trying many cards and buying pre-built cards and replacing kernel.img, none of them work. I found out that that was because of the RPI3 used kernel7.img, however, using the makefile that Alex gave us, I was unable to build a working OS. Could anyone tell me how to build kernel7.img using arm-none-eabi?
Thanks,

ndrewffght

I'm using mingw on windows 10.

Comment: that tutorial is old afaik, pi1 not pi3.  there is a bare metal forum at raspberrypi.org that has lots of good info on bare metal for the pi, all flavors.  the latest bootloader from the pi folks will look for various different file names in order, kernel7.img is on the list.  Not sure what you were trying to do but it could be that your image was built fine, just the code wont work on the pi 3.

Comment: for example kernel8.img (aarch64) then kernel8-32.img (arm/aarch32) then kernel7.img (arm) and lastly kernel.img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the tutorial was old, so I switched to a new tutorial [Here](https://archive.fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/programming_rpi3/attachments/slides/1475/export/events/attachments/programming_rpi3/slides/1475/bare_metal_rpi3.pdf) that does 64 - bit bare metal.